# htc evo 3d wifi connected but internet not working

Tags: wi-fi, htc, htc-evo, htc-evo-3d

this is my first question on android, so I hope I will not miss anything. I bought my phone from friend probably 5 years ago, so there is no warranty. I used to login to wifi networks with no problems, but probably yesterday I clicked on "save network" (my wireless home network). For some reason, it stored my network with weird ip address(169.254.169.59), that I can not delete from phone.
My router automatically asignes 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, ...
I tried renaming my wifi SSID and connected to it. Again, ip address in my mobile phone is 169.254.169.59. I tried connecting to two different wifi routers, my mobile still has this weird ip address.
I also tried connecting to that saved network manually with ip address I set (192.168.0.15). After connecting, my phone claims it has ip address 169.254.169.59.
How do I get rid of this saved ip address? I tried reseting my phone. I do not see any other usefull settings in my phone. I can not delete saved network (I did not see any options for deletion).

- Android version - 4.0.3
- HTC sense 3.6
- Software number = 3.28.401.1
- kernel = 3.0.16-ge733186

How do I fix this? Is it possible without factory defaults reset? My phone has never had a jail break.

Comment: That IP address received by your phone looks interesting here: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=169.254.%3F.%3F

Comment: That is interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably made a mistake that I thought I had two routers, but actually I had router and wifi extender. I was working with extender as router, trying to restart it and alter settings. But after I intalled main router, my mobile connected. So I guess main router had saved that weird ip address for my device and kept it. Restarting main router made it work.